# Unable to implement Interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

I'm an 18 year old apprentice in c# programming (specificly in OOP 'structure')

I'm currently trying to learn the use/usefullness of Interfaces, but.. I have a VERY hard time trying to actually use Interfaces, I've decided to start working on problems from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/archives). What I want to do with these problems is to try and implement Interfaces or anything I need to learn so that I get some experience with it.

I'm currently at [Problem 2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) but I can't think of a way to implement Interfaces.

So in general what I would like to ask is, what and how can I do this (please don't give me the final result, I am only looking for an idea or help to get started)

I feel like I'm stuck in a hole, unable to continue, so I would love some inspiration, examples or litteraly anything where I can get good and concise information! :)

In advance, thank you very much for your help/constructive criticism.

-Kindest Regards, Niklas

Comment: Actually, problem 2 doesn't need you to implement interfaces, right?

Comment: Interfaces aren't usefull in that tiny applications. It's more about big applications.

Comment: For that sort of question you need to look into `recursion`, not interfaces. Interfaces are useful when you need to communicate with some other module, thus you use an interface to provide a set of methods which need to be there. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b5b8ezk(v=vs.90).aspx) for more information on the matter. Also as a rule of thumb, it is the situation which determines the design of your code, and not the other way round.

Comment: @Sweeper, you're right, but it's not so much about the fact that it needs interfaces, it's about that I want to implement them, so I can both, get some practice in creating interfaces and also that I can learn when to use them. (I plan to continue with Interfaces/other things in Project Euler. So hopefully at one of the Problems, I'll be able to get the full use of Interfaces)

Comment: @MajkeloDev, You're right as well, but I can't force myself to create big 'fake' applications so that I can get practice with Interfaces, I find it much easier when there is already instructions on what the program requires. Therefor I figured it would be easier to learn something if I just have to solve it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fibonacci sequence is... well... a sequence. Hence, it can:

1. Return an item by index
2. Return next number

I would suggest creating an interface `ISequence` with a single method `GetNextElement()`.

```
public interface ISequence
{
    int GetNextElement();
}
```

Then you can implement this interface in a `FibonacciSequence` class:

```
public class FibonacciSequence : ISequence
{
    private int _lastElement1 = 0;
    private int _lastElement2 = 1;

    public int GetNextElement()
    {
        int result = _lastElement1 + _lastElement2;
        _lastElement1 = _lastElement2;
        _lastElement2 = result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to implement other sequences such as arithmetic progression, etc.

**P.S.** I must admit, that doing interfaces for that particular problem is not the best idea, but for learning purposes - why not! :)

Comment: I like that idea becaus there are several assignments there which produce sequences. Now the OP can write a program for output and input and such which handles sequences in a generic manner and "plug in" concrete implementations. Because, among us, I'd probably just have copied the boiler plate code over to my next tiny project...

Comment: And then you can have different classes implementing that interface. For example:  `public class StandardSequence : ISequence { private int _lastElement=0; public int GetNextElement() { return _lastElement++; } }`

Comment: `public class RandomSequence : ISequence { private static readonly _random = new Random(); public int GetNextElement() { return _random.Next(); } }`

Comment: If you want an interface to represent a sequence you really shouldn't be writing your own, you should be re-using `IEnumerable` so that your sequence is compatible with the wide range of .NET code that is designed to work with sequences (most notably LINQ).

Comment: Can I quickly ask, what does the '_' in the variable names mean? I've seen it before, but I got the idea that it was used for Event names, have I misunderstood or is it different from each programmer?

Comment: There are naming conventions. I personally use the one where it says that private non-static fields should be prefixed with underscore. It has no functional meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are, in my opinion, a software engineering tool. Can you use them on things like Project Euler questions? Absolutely! They are a tool, after all.... But the usefulness of them are minimal and very debatable.

If you want to learn how interfaces apply to the real world, I strongly recommend that you study Design Patterns.

Some resources to get you started:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) - Free resource but you are left to your devices
- [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)  - Best software engineering book I've read... Covers design patterns well and shows actual usages of Interfaces. Note that book's programming language is Java but this truly does not matter. OOP is OOP no matter the language.

This is not all there is to say about Interfaces, mind you, but it's a *common* real world scenario that you see interfaces used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ISequence` and the like, I'd rather implement something like that:

```
  public static class Sequences {
    // Instead of reinveting the wheel (ISequence etc.), let's return  
    // IEnumerable<long> which is specially designed for such a cases
    public static IEnumerable<long> Fibonacci(long first, long second) {
      yield return first;
      yield return second;

      while (true) {
        long result = first + second;

        first = second;
        second = result;

        yield return result;
      }
    }
  }

  ...

  // Test: 10 first Fibonacci numbers:
  // 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89
  Console.Write(String.Join(", ", Sequences.Fibonacci(1, 2).Take(10)));

  ...

  // Now having Fibonacci as IEnumerable<long>
  // you can easily answer a lot of questions via Linq:
  long result = Sequences.Fibonacci(1, 2)
    .TakeWhile(item => item < 4000000) // up to 4 millions
    .Where(item => item % 2 == 0)      // take even items only
    .Sum();                            // sum them up
```

implementing any interfaces just *for the sake of implementing* interfaces is a bad practice.

Comment: The point here of course is not that interfaces aren't useful with respect to this problem, but rather that .NET *has already created the appropriate interface* and so the OP doesn't need to (and in fact shouldn't) create his own new interface for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are in essence a contract - a blueprint if you will that describes what features code implementing the interface (i.e. the concretion) should provide.

Interfaces can be a difficult topic to fully get a handle on without an appreciation of their applications.

Here are few of them:

**Multiple inheritance**

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance i.e. deriving from more than one class so implementing multiple interfaces is really your only choice here.

**Mocking frameworks**

Mocking frameworks are used where you wish to mimic the behaviour of an object but not actually run it. You might want to do this when unit testing some software without connecting to a real service or database for example. You simply drop in the interface and then describe what outputs are expected for given input and it will create a mock object that behaves exactly like the concretion.

**IOC**

Inversion of control is a mechanism whereby interfaces are used in lieu of concretions throughout the relevant code base. Exact implementations vary from framework to framework but usually they involve some sort of factory whereby you define which interface you're using and the concretion and then the concretion implementing the interface gets passed round through the layers as required. The good thing is you can readily swap out concretions in the factory without having to update upstream code.

---

Some sample code where a routine can handle either concretion due to variables and parameters being defined as interfaces rather than concretions:

```
 public class Teaching
    {       
        public void RunTests()
        {
            ObjectA a = new ObjectA();
            ObjectB b = new ObjectB();
            IContract c = new ObjectA();
            IContract d = new ObjectB();

            Test1(a);
            Test1(b); // Won't compile

            Test2(b);
            Test2(a); // Won't compile

            // Test3 can handle either concretion            
            Test3(c); 
            Test3(d); 
        }

        private void Test1(ObjectA obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.GetExcited("Yeah"));
        }

        private void Test2(ObjectB obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.GetExcited("Yeah"));
        }

        private void Test3(IContract obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.GetExcited("Yeah"));
        }

    }

    public class ObjectA : IContract
    {

        public string GetExcited(string data)
        {
            return data + "!";
        }
    }

    public class ObjectB : IContract
    {

        public string GetExcited(string data)
        {
            return data + "!!";
        }
    }

    public interface IContract
    {
        string GetExcited(string data);
    }
```